# how to make eclipse + tomcat instant deploy for webapps

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I build a maven project and deploy this war into tomcat webapps folder then started tomcat, so that my app available in browser as `localhost:8080/myApp`

I can see `myApp` folder which was extracted from `myApp.war` under `tomcat/webapps`.

I can modify this app's UI by editing files under`tomcat/webapps/myApp/..` using Notepad++.

I send this project to my co-worker, he also import this project in his eclipse and run this app.

He changed the jsp and js files from eclipse and the result will be reflected in browser, he never used separate editor to this modification.

If I change the files in eclipse then it is not reflected in browser.

What I need to do for the same to be working to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want Hot deploy in Eclipse, please try to take following steps:

1. Double clicks on the Tomcat plugin, refer to publishing tab, make sure Automatically publish when resources change is selected. This should be the default option, to support “hot deploy” resources, for example : JSP, XML and properties files.
   [image]
   [image]
2. In the Tomcat Plugin page, clicks on the Module view, make sure Auto Reload is Disabled. Default is enabled.
   [image]

   > **Note:**
   >   This is an important step, failed to set the auto reload to disabled, the Tomcat server will be restarted every time you modified something!
3. Start Project in DEBUG mode. Hot Deploy is supported in DEBUG mode only.

> **Limitation**
>   Hot deploy has supported the code changes in the method implementation only. If you add a new class or a new method, restart is still required.
>
> To simulate it, try to add a new method, following pop up screen will be displayed, saying the code changes cannot be hot swapped in the JVM.